# Can I get a diff of my changes before submitting an edit?

Tags: feature-request, edits, diff, edit-summary

When editing a post I usually want to write a concise summary (especially when suggesting an edit).

This would be much easier if I was able to get a diff for my changes. Sometimes editing a post takes quite some time and at the end I don't remember what I changed in the beginning.

Comment: This is **really** useful when making large edits to FAQ posts here.

Comment: Just to add, sometimes I'll make a bunch of changes, but then when looking at the diff after, I'll change my mind and revert them. This would be a lot easier if I saw the diff before submitting.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a diff checker. E.g [diff checker](https://www.diffchecker.com).

Make sure to copy/paste the original post into the diff checker before editing, then you can always get the diff while editing the post.

Comment: I think the questioner was interested in a more integrated solution.

Comment: Yes probably, but just wanted to add the answer as a temporary solution, SE updates don’t come right away :)

Comment: Thank you for the idea - it **is** a workaround.

Comment: This is useful, but I can't find anything that uses quite the same diff engine (or settings) as SO, so the results often look weird.

Answer (score 8):

After editing you can click on the "[Edited X ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/322016/revisions)" link, and see the differences highlighted.

You then have less than 5 minutes to read and summarize your changes, and place them onto the "Edit Summary" line. If you complete your one-liner within the grace period it will appear as a single edit.

Despite the ease of doing that, a checkbox in the Editor would be a great addition.

[image: Show the Diff Checkbox]

That would put all the information together on the same screen.

Comment: I didn't think of the grace period in this way, but you are right.

Comment: If the edit window were bigger that would help too, a lot to fit on the page and accommodate all screen widths, here's hoping this request is successful.

Comment: One problem with relying on the grace period is you might run into a conflict with another user's concurrent, approved edit.  I just had that happen -- twice on the same question -- as I tried to edit my original edit.

Comment: Note that some sites like SO will silently drop changes to the summary during the grace period unless you change something else as well.